# MongoMock and mongoengine not clearing database

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, mongomock

During unittesting I'm calling:

```
self.connection = connect(db="testdb", host="mongomock://localhost")
self.connection.drop_database("testdb")
```

between tests, however data is persisting. Is there a known fix for this?

Comment: Hello james, did you find any workarounds?

Comment: I just created a loop to loop over my collections and drop them, not ideal but got me going and made the test reliable.

Comment: Can confirm that database drop works on mongoengine v0.18.2.